# Fail to enable Workload identity on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, workload-identity

I have several clusters where were `enabled` workload identity with `terraform` without any issues.

But faced with problem only on one of them.

`Error` from `terraform`:

```
Error waiting for updating GKE cluster workload identity config: DeployPatch failed
```

The same issue throw `Google Cloud Console`

One `important` detail:

few months ago all permissions were reseted and i restored it manually.

Please, help resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer on this question, even not answer only way how to restore needed permissions.

Just go to another project (or create new one) and compare permissions on VM with your current.