# GKE cluster upgrade failed with "DeployPatch failed" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My cluster upgrade failed:

```
gcloud beta container operations describe "operation-sdfsdfsdf" --zone us-central1

clusterConditions:
- canonicalCode: UNKNOWN
  message: DeployPatch failed
detail: DeployPatch failed
endTime: '2022-06-30T12:36:48.246662261Z'
error:
  code: 2
  message: DeployPatch failed
name: operation-sdfsdfsdf
operationType: UPGRADE_NODES
progress:
  metrics:
  - intValue: '7'
    name: NODES_TOTAL
  - intValue: '1'
    name: NODES_FAILED
  - intValue: '6'
    name: NODES_COMPLETE
  - intValue: '7'
    name: NODES_DONE
  - intValue: '2454'
    name: NODE_PDB_DELAY_SECONDS
selfLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxx/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-sdfsdfsdf
startTime: '2022-06-30T10:36:14.709547456Z'
status: DONE
statusMessage: DeployPatch failed
targetLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxx/locations/us-central1/clusters/mycluster/nodePools/mypool
zone: us-central1
```

This is the only thing I've been able to find with this same error: [Fail to enable Workload identity on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547098/fail-to-enable-workload-identity-on-gke)

I searched github as well. This error is no where in google's docs.

I also see zero error logs on the nodes.

Comment: Please share more information about your cluster. Did you have the proper permission to perform the update? Are you able to enable Workload Identity in your cluster? Are you using tTerraform?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I'm the project editor and I can't upgrade from 1.22 to 1.24 or 1.23. I'm trying to upgrade through the Console.